# Got the time of day?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm stuck in a hole, and I cannot for the life of me dig myself out of it.

This is a highly aesthetics question, but I like to get what I ask for from my code.
I'm trying to parse a string representing time to a DateTime variable that I then send to a textBox as well as to my LINQ query.

I would like to represent my time in this format: "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" and that is what i get from my Select query, but as soon a I try to parse what the user has written in the textBox to DateTime it gives me "1/13/2011 12:00:00 AM", even if it was in the format "2011-01-13 00:00:00".

I feel like I've tried everything to make this work, but there must be a solution, can you guys help me find it? What IFormatProvider am I suppose to use?

This is what i tried:

```
//textBox1.Text =   "2011-01-13 00:00:00";
DateTime = TimeFrom;    
TimeFrom = DateTime.ParseExact(textBox1.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", null);
TimeFrom = DateTime.ParseExact(textBox1.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns(), new CultureInfo("sv-SE"), DateTimeStyles.None); 
TimeFrom = DateTime.ParseExact(textBox1.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns(), new CultureInfo("sv-SE"),System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
TimeFrom = DateTime.ParseExact("2008-10-01 16:44:12.000", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
textBox1.Text = TimeFrom.ToString();
```

But none of it gives me the formatting that I so crave.

**UPDATE:**
It appears that somehow the Current Culture got changed from the time I declared my DateTime variable to the time I wanted to Parse the textBox1.Text value from "sv-SE" to "en-EN" which is why it decided to change the way my time was formatted. It is not something I'm doing in my code. Any ideas as to why?

Why it decided to ignore my `(IFormatProvider) new CultureInfo("sv-SE",true)`, is something I haven't figured out yet ether.

If you have any suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: It's your `ToString` that uses the wrong format, and not your parser. The `DataTime` struct does know about formatting. It only saves the time.

Comment: I beg to differ. The first time I write my DateTime to the UI it has the right formatting. But after parsing that string back to DateTime it changes it formatting in the DateTime variable, according to debug.

Comment: You can't trust what it shows in the debugger...it's just calling ToString() on it, which is merely one representation of what the DateTime object really is.

Comment: Oh, that is somewhat annoying. I thought the debugger was like a alter ego of Jon Skeet. But it doesn't change the fact that if I type DateTime time = DateTime.now; it gets the formatting I want.

Comment: Well then that's weird.  AFAIK, calling Parse doesn't store the IFormatProvider with the DateTime.

Comment: The 1st statement won't compile. And maybe wrap those other lines a little?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing means to take a string and turn it into a strongly-typed DateTime object, using a  format.

To turn that strongly-typed DateTime object into a string, you call `ToString` using a format.

```
TimeFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

Edit: Maybe you just need to set the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE")` before you start doing stuff.  Is this an ASP.NET app?

Comment: I realize that is what Parsing is for, that is why I'm using it. I don't want to "Cast" my DateTime into the specified format every time I write it to a log, or the UI if I can get around it.

Comment: Well that's an entirely different question :)  Basically when you call ToString() it's doing exactly this with a predefined format.  How to override the base ToString() format: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingEvilOverridingSystemDateTimesDefaultToString.aspx

Comment: Ah, interesting. But wouldn't it just be easier to get the format the correct way to begin with? In the parsing I mean. I am guessing that its possible, anything else would be silly in my mind.

Answer (score 4):

```
textBox1.Text = TimeFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

or something like:

```
textBox1.Text = TimeFrom.ToString(new CultureInfo("sv-SE"));
```

depending on what you need exactly.

Comment: Good point, maybe he just needs to switch his thread's culture.

Comment: Indeed Greg. :) Kudos to you. However, I have to change the Culture every time I run my function, any thoughts?

Comment: It really depends on your application's architecture.  If you're always dealing with "sv-SE", set it when the application starts up, or if you're using ASP.NET, in the web.config.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
TimeFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

You need to format `DateTime` only when you convert it to `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx)? To print out the string in a certain format take a look at [format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Comment: I have, and it unfortunately didn't help. TimeFrom = DateTime.ParseExact(textBox1.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys. I just wanted to go public with what caused my problems.

What happened was that when I rendered a report and loaded it into a report viewer the CurrentCulture got changed to en-EN. The report language was set to blank which leads me to believe that the default language is en-EN.

This then changed the way that my time was represented. A DateTime variable does not remember its formatting culture. So any changes in representing a DateTime as a string has to contain the string formatting, like this: `dateTimeVariable.toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")`

I hope someone will find this helpfull.